# Referencing updated table name in trigger

Tags: triggers, sql-server-2012

I would like to create an insert trigger, applied to several tables, that adds information to another table that is basically tracking changes made to the first table (the ones with the trigger attached).

I would like to add which table was updated to the tracking table but I am not sure how to reference the name of the table that had data inserted.

```
CREATE TRIGGER trgAfterInsert ON dbo.MyTable
FOR INSERT
AS  
    insert into dbo.TrackingTable
           ([TableAltered],[RecordIdentifier],[DateAltered]) 
    SELECT NameOfTriggeredTable, ID, Now()
    FROM inserted;
```

What I cannot figure out is where to get `NameOfTriggeredTable`

Comment: @marc_s - That makes sense! Make your comment as an answer and I will vote it as answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the trigger is

```
CREATE TRIGGER trgAfterInsert ON dbo.MyTable
                              **************
```

I'd say you just put `'dbo.MyTable'` there.

It cannot be anything else, it's a constant, really. A trigger is always on exactly **one** table only.